# Copying a smaller array into a larger one

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to think of the most elegant/simple way of doing this. Perhaps I'm overthinking it a little.

Lets say I've got a 5x5 array of integers that looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

And another 2x2 array of integers that looks like this:

```
5 1
2 3
```

I want to pick a location in the 5x5 array, say [2][2], and place the values from the second array into the first, so it looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 5 1 0
0 0 2 3 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

My initial thought was to use a for loop after determining the number of rows/columns in the array to be copied, but I can't seem to puzzle out a way in my head to do that this morning.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Sorry, here's the way I'm doing it currently. Just wondering if there's a better way.

This is actually part of a unity thing I'm doing - "RoomDoors" is our smaller array, and "map" is the larger array it's being moved into. It's part of a random map generator that needs to know which "edges" of tiles in rooms have doors on them that can connect to other rooms. RoomDoors stores 4 booleans, one for each direction telling me if there's a door there.

```
    roomDoors = previousRoom.GetComponent<RoomDataInterface> ().rooms; //2d array of room/door arrangement in new room
    sizeCol = roomDoors.GetLength (0);
    sizeRow = roomDoors.GetLength (1);
    map [10, 10] = roomDoors [0, 0]; // top left of the room goes in the spot
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeCol; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeRow; j ++) {
            map [i + 10,j + 10] = roomDoors[i,j];
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Sorry but this is not a good way to ask a question. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: What about two nested `for` loops, one for the columns and one for the rows? Some index checking can also be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my current code into the post.

Comment: The question asks for beautification of working code, which makes it also suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
map [10, 10] = roomDoors [0, 0];
```

is redundant, as the same assignment will be performed by the first iteration of the loop. Removal of the line will result in a solution that is smaller and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do much better, just remove the unnecessary assignment:

```
roomDoors = previousRoom.GetComponent<RoomDataInterface> ().rooms;
sizeCol = roomDoors.GetLength (0);
sizeRow = roomDoors.GetLength (1);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeCol; i ++)
  for (int j = 0; j < sizeRow; j ++) 
    map [i + 10, j + 10] = roomDoors[i, j];
```